# Matching Regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

my program contains **ascii.txt** to match patterns from it.
my program is to implement `sed` command, just to try write perl code because I am studying perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# sed command implementation
use strict;
use warnings;
use subs qw(read_STDIN read_FILE usage);
use IO::File;
use constant {
    SEARCH_PRINT => 0,
};

our $proj_name = $0;

main(@ARGV);

sub main
{
    if(scalar @_ == 2) {
        read_FILE @_;

    }
    else {
        usage 
    }
}

sub read_FILE {
    my ($sed_script, $file_name) = @_;
    my $parsed_val =  parse_sed_script($sed_script);
    if( $parsed_val == SEARCH_PRINT ) {
        search_print_lines($sed_script, $file_name);
    }
}

sub parse_sed_script {
    my $command = shift or return;
    if($command =~ /^\/([^\/].)*\/$/) {
        return SEARCH_PRINT;
    }
}

sub search_print_lines {
    my ($script, $file) = @_;
    my $fh = IO::File->new($file, "r") or error("no file found $file");
    while( $_ = $fh->getline ) {
        print if $_ =~ $script
    }
}

sub usage {
    message("Usage: $proj_name sed-script [file]")
}

sub error
{
    my $e = shift || 'unkown error';
    print("$0: $e\n");
    exit 0;
}
```

When I execute from the shell: `sed.pl /Test/ ascii.txt`

I found that `print if $_ =~ $script`, doesn't execute because of the REGEX is stored in scalar variable

the **ascii.txt** contains.

```
Test 1
REGEX TEST
```

When I use `print $script` in `search_print_lines` subroutine it prints the regex sent by the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass something in on the command line and use it in your script, the entire literal text is used.  So if you pass in `/Test/`, it will see those slashes as literals, so the "real" regular expression it's looking at is something like `\/Test\/` (escaping the slashes, because now it's looking for them.  Try passing in the regex without the // surrounding it.

If your goal is to allow the // to show that it's a regular expression, I would remove them when the program starts.

One more edit:  If you want to be able to pass in flags, you'd need to eval the input somehow.

```
$script = '/Test/i';
eval { "\$regex = $script" };
```

and then

```
"REGEX TEST" =~ $regex
```

should return true.  Doing an eval like this is highly insecure, though.

edit: what happens in `eval` is that whatever's in the block is executed.  So what happens in the eval above is that you're dynamically creating a regular expression and setting it to a variable.  That allows you to use regular expression flags like i without having to do any special parsing of the command-line input.  When the eval is executed, it will be as if you had typed in `$regex = /Test/i`.  Then you can compare your text to `$regex` and it will work.  I thought about this because your example would not work unless you had the i flag set to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: I don't understand, I need some explanation, please.

Comment: If you send in "/Test/" it isn't going to match "REGEX TEST" because "REGEX TEST" doesn't contain any slashes.  Does that make sense?  If it's something else that you're not understanding, please let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I don't understand /\/$script\// and eval ?

Comment: I edited my original reply to hopefully make it clearer what I was saying.  The documentation for eval is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) - looking at this may help you understand.  If using `eval` makes things too complicated for right now, you can ignore that part and just keep in mind not to pass in the // characters in the command-line argument.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't remove the slashes from $sed_script variable. After I modified your read_FILE function, it started to work:

```
sub read_FILE {
    my ($sed_script, $file_name) = @_;
    my $parsed_val =  parse_sed_script($sed_script);

    if( $parsed_val == SEARCH_PRINT ) {
        $sed_script =~ s/^\/(.*)\/$/$1/;

        #you can also parse the regexp
        #$sed_script = qr/$sed_script/;
        search_print_lines($sed_script, $file_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine, but what is wrong with the //, why does it work if the // is removed?

Comment: @UNIX It searches not for 'Test', but for '/Test/'

Comment: If it is true, when I replace my code with print if $_ =~ /Test/;
It works
which is the same as $_ =~ $script;

Comment: @UNIX No, it is not the same. In the second case Perl doesn't interpret slashes as delimiters of a regular expression. It just invisibly adds another pair of slashes, and you get 2 pairs of slashes.

Comment: @UNIX I recommend to uncomment the line `#$sed_script = qr/$sed_script/;` and then use Data::Dumper to print the value of $sed_script with removed slashes and without them. So you could see the internals of the regular expression.